# Updating string field with a path by using Field calculator . Version 3.18.2

Tags: qgis, path, field-calculator

Us it possible to update newly made  string type field (column) with a path to a file on a local drive by using "field calculator".

I tried with first defining type of field as "String" then opening "Field Calculator" and pasting the path for all the features, in the attribute. Instead of getting "normal" path, I get path with a number of question marks. And this doesn't work of course.

Is there perhaps a way around this?

Comment: Did you remember to use single parenthesis' (`'`)?

Comment: used, but nothing

Comment: Please provide input and ouput examples.

Comment: which operating system are you on? if it's windows either use `/` or `\\ `

Comment: In Field calculator I use like this 'C:\Users\mirmar\Desktop\...' and get something like C:?sers?irmar?esktop?.... after FC has been used